# How to change only minimum cell's color in html tables

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, html-table

Assume I have HTML tables and by clicking, I would like to change colors.

My desired result is if `5` and`6` are clicked, the cell `5` becomes green and the others will become red.

in other words, only *minimum number* among clicked cells will become green

Is it possible? Is there any method?

My attempt is also snippetted.

[image]

```js
$(function() {
  $("td").click(function() {
    $(this).addClass("hospitalization");
  });
});
```

```css
.hospitalization {
  background-color: red;
}

.hospitalization_second {
  background-color: green;
}

td {
  padding: 5px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <td id="1">1</td>
  <td id="2">2</td>
  <td id="3">3</td>
  <td id="4">4</td>
  <td id="5">5</td>
  <td id="6">6</td>
  <td id="7">7</td>
  <td id="8">8</td>
  <td id="9">9</td>
  <td id="10">10</td>
</table>
```

Comment: If the values are always in order, you could just do `$('.hospitalization:first').addClass('green')`

Comment: Assign the cells a class name then you can use $(".class") to address all elements using that class or use $("td") but the later is flawed if you have td's that are not related.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this particular order, you can add a class "green" to the first element that has the class hospitalization.

```js
$(function() {
  $("td").click(function() {
    $(this).addClass("hospitalization");
    $("td.hospitalization-green").removeClass("hospitalization-green");
    $("td.hospitalization").first().addClass("hospitalization-green");
  });
});
```

```css
.hospitalization {
  background-color: red;
}
.hospitalization-green {
  background-color: green;
}
td {
  padding:5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <td id="1">1</td>
  <td id="2">2</td>
  <td id="3">3</td>
  <td id="4">4</td>
  <td id="5">5</td>
  <td id="6">6</td>
  <td id="7">7</td>
  <td id="8">8</td>
  <td id="9">9</td>
  <td id="10">10</td>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks ! If there is not  `id` attribute in tables, Is it work well?  I couldn't see `first()` method mechanism.. Best regards.

Comment: Yes, it works without id attributes, because this is a simple approach based on the order of the elements, not on attributes or content. The ``first()`` method selects the first element of the list made by the jQuery selector.

Answer (score 2):

In case the id order does not follow the same order as the html elements order
In the code below, the class first will be removed when clicked, to prevent the class first piling up with each new click.

Then we check which of the clicked elements has the lowest id number. The number with the lowest id is regarded as the first, and will get the first class.

To ensure we only select hospitalization in the clicked table, you can use 
const parent_table = $(this).closest('table');
to ensure you only change the table that was clicked in.

```js
$(function() {
  $("td").click(function() {
    $(this).addClass("hospitalization");
    // select the table that was clicked in
    constparent_table = $(this).closest('table');
    // remove the old first class
    $(parent_table).find('.hospitalization').removeClass('first');

    // check which element now is the first element. 
    // In this case I used the id to define which element is first;
    const first = $(parent_table).find('.hospitalization').sort((a, b) => a.id - b.id)[0];

    // add the class first to the first element
    $(first).addClass('first');
  });
});
```

```css
.hospitalization {
    background-color:red;
}

.hospitalization.first {
    background-color:green;
}

td {
  padding:5px
  }
```

```html
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <table>
        <td id="1">1</td>
        <td id="2">2</td>
        <td id="3">3</td>
        <td id="4">4</td>
        <td id="5">5</td>
        <td id="6">6</td>
        <td id="7">7</td>
        <td id="8">8</td>
        <td id="9">9</td>
        <td id="10">10</td>
        </table>
        <table>
        <td id="11">11</td>
        <td id="12">12</td>
        <td id="13">13</td>
        <td id="14">14</td>
        <td id="15">15</td>
        <td id="16">16</td>
        <td id="17">17</td>
        <td id="18">18</td>
        <td id="19">19</td>
        <td id="20">20</td>
        </table>
```

Comment: Answers which explain the code presented get downvoted less often than those which do not.

Comment: im adding explanation to it atm:)

Comment: note: this only works when there is 1 table, do you need an example that supports multiple tables on the same page(since u asked tables (plural))?

Comment: Thanks, I wish I could see examples of multiple tables, thanks !

Comment: @Heisenberg edited the answer to support multiple tables

Answer (score 0):

You don't need jQuery for that. Here's a JS version assuming the structure you've mentioned:

```
(function() {
    window.onload = () => {
        const table = document.body.querySelector('table');
        const cells = table.querySelectorAll('td');

        table.addEventListener('click', ({target}) => {
            if (target.tagName.toLowerCase() !== 'td') return;

            const minimal = table.querySelector('.hospitalized_second');

            if(!minimal) {
                target.className = 'hospitalized_second';
                return;
            }

            if (parseInt(target.innerText, 10) < parseInt(minimal.innerText, 10)) {
                minimal.className = 'hospitalized';
                target.className = 'hospitalized_second';
            } else {
                target.className = 'hospitalized';
            }
        });
    }
})();
```